# Sum amounts on line click checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this `while` loop I have a list of values:

```
<?php
while($row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($res_list)) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="cost" value="'.$row_list['bedrag_incl'].'">'.$row_list['bedrag_incl'];
} ?>
```

When I click the checkbox, I need the total of clicked items to be summed up to it's total and display here:

```
<input type="text" id="bedragen_selected" name="bedragen_selected" value="" size="5" style="text-align:right;background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" />
```

To achieve this I have this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
var sum = 0;

$('.cost').live('click',function()
{
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
    else
    {
        sum = sum - parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
    $('#bedragen_selected').val(sum);
}
);
</script>
```

For some reason there is no result displayed or even an error given. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked if `$('.cost').live('click',function()
{}` is being called ?

Comment: I replaced your click function with `$(document).on('click', '.cost', function(){` and [it is working properly](https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lxth2f/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.

```
$(document).on('click', '.cost', function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.cost:checked').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#bedragen_selected").val(total);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cost', function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.cost:checked').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#bedragen_selected").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cost" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cost" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cost" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cost" value="4">4<br>
<input type="text" id="bedragen_selected" name="bedragen_selected" value="" size="5" style="text-align:right;background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$(".cost").change(function(){
  calculate();
});


function calculate(){
    var sum = 0;

    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
      sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

    alert(sum);
}
```